# Creating Dialog Box with Different Contents when Hovering on Different Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to create a list of links, and when the mouse is over different links, a dialog box appears to show a short summary content of that link. The content should be different for different links. Then when the mouse leaves the link, the box automatically disappears. Here is my current code using jQuery UI:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
     function hovIn(){
        $("#info1").dialog({
            open : function ( event, ui ) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        },
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        position: { my: 'center center', at: 'center top+300', within: window },
        autoOpen: true,
        modal : false,
        });
    }
    function hovOut() {
        $("#info1").dialog('close');          
    }

    $("#id1").hover(hovIn, hovOut);
    $("#id2").hover(hovIn, hovOut);
});

</script>
<body>
<a href=next.htm id='id1'>Link1</a><br><br><br>
<a href=back.htm id='id2'>Link2</a>
<div id='info1' title='Hello' style='display:none'>
<p id='info1_link'>How are you?</p></div>
<div id='info2' title='Goodbye' style='display:none'>
<p id='info2_link'>See you next time</p></div>
</body>
```

The same message appears when mouse is over each of the 2 links. Any simple way that saves the need to create many pairs of `hovIn` and `hovOut` functions for different links? Or, is there a way to pass the title or text contents into the `hovIn` and `hovOut` functions?
(A side question is, the dialog box keeps flashing when I use `modal : true`. How can this be fixed?)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question on the dialog showing the same content all the time. You should be able to check the target id's (tags) of the source that triggered the hover events like below and accordingly create the dialog.

By inserting below lines at the top of functions hovIn and hovOut, dialogs can be created using the appropriate div tags.

```
var targetDiv;
if (event.target.id == "id1") {
    targetDiv = "#info1";
} else if (event.target.id == "id2") {
    targetDiv = "#info2";
}
$(targetDiv).dialog({
....
```